# 400 error, nginx debug log confusion, Django app

Tags: nginx, django

When I go to `test.example.com`, I get a page that just says `Bad Request (400)`.

I'm running a Django app located at `/home/django/product_blog`.

Here are the contents of my nginx file at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/BRBR2`.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name test.example.com;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/django/product_blog;
    }

    location / {
        include         uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass      unix:/home/django/product_blog/product_blog.sock;
    }
}
```

When I go to the debug file after trying to load the site, I see this: https://pastebin.com/GchPd1MD.

The file at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` shows nothing.

How do I find the source of the 400 error?

Comment: That comes from Django. Check your application settings. In particular [the ALLOWED_HOSTS list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19875789/1068283).

Comment: Check the uwsgi log, then.

Comment: I ran `sudo reboot` and `sudo service nginx configtest && sudo service nginx restart`. Now the site loads just fine. I don't know which of those two commands did it.

Comment: Most likely rebooting, because that's the only one of those commands that would have affected uwsgi.

Comment: Also, django's default validation doesn't allow underscores in host names, so check that isn't the issue too:  https://blog.anvileight.com/posts/how-to-fix-bad-request-400-in-django/